# Writing tests for class using TableGateway ZF2/ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have a problem with making a test.

I have made a function in my class that counts all the rows in a database table. To access to the database i use Zend Frameworks [TableGateway class](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php). My problem is that i don't know how to write a test for the function.

One way to look on it is that the function is so simple that it needs no tests but it would be nice to know how i can make it work.

There is no function on the AbstractTableGateway that allow me to set the internal variable $adapter. How can i set the protected variable $adapter?

**Function**

```
public function count()
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ". $this->tableGateway->getTable();
    $statement = $this->tableGateway->adapter->query($sql);
    $result    = $statement->execute()->current();
    return $result['Count'];
}
```

**Test for function**

```
public function testCount()
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM DbTable";

    $result = $this->prophesize(Result::class);
    $result->current()->willReturn(["Count" => 10]);

    $statement = $this->prophesize(Statement::class);
    $statement->execute()->willReturn($result);

    $adapter = $this->prophesize(Adapter::class);
    $adapter->query($sql)->willReturn($statement);

    $this->tableGateway->adapter = $adapter;

    $this->assertSame(10, $this->DbTable->count());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableGateway` gets its adapter from constructor. Whatever factory creates `TableGateway` instance at your `$this->tableGateway` property, should pass your mock adapter (or real adapter if this is aimed as integration test) to its constructor.